# Event turbolinks:load working strange

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Please help my. I use rails5 with gem turbolinks. My navigation menu code:

```
<div id="templatemo_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="level_0 index" href="/">Главная</a></li>

      <li><a class="level_0 about" href="/pages/about">О нас</a></li>

      <li><a class="level_0 portfolio" href="/type_works">Портфолио</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=1">Corporate Metrics Liaison</a></li>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=2">Chief Solutions Planner</a></li>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=3">Central Applications Architect</a></li>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=4">Global Metrics Executive</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a class="level_0 blog" href="/blog_articles">Блог</a></li>

      <li><a class="level_0 contact" href="/contact_messages/new">Контакт</a></li>
    </ul>

    <br style="clear: left">
  </div>
```

I need to after clicking on the '.about', BODY background changed to red. But now after clicking BODY background not changed. Its problem.

My attempt to solve:

```
var menuActivePunkt = function(){ 
  var pathname = location.pathname,
    pathnameList = pathname.split('/'),
    slug1 = pathnameList[1],
    slug2 = pathnameList[2];

  console.log('slug1', slug1);
  console.log('slug2', slug2);

  $('#templatemo_menu a').removeClass('selected').on('click', function() {
    if(slug1 == 'pages' && slug2 == 'about') {
      //$('.index').addClass('selected');
      $('body').css({'background': 'red'});
    };
  });
}


$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  menuActivePunkt();
})
```

Comment: have you added `//= require turbolinks` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `JQuery` on to this page. **So**

**First:** You have to require `jquery-turbolinks gem`.

**Second:** Edit you `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

`//= require jquery`

`//= require jquery.turbolinks`

`//= require turbolinks`

Hope this help you!